# Shell Script para download do PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, script, shell

Estou escrevendo um código em Shell Script para baixar o código fonte da ultima versão atualizada do PostgreSQL verificando no link a versão atual de forma automática.

Então com base nisso eu fiz o seguinte:

criei a variavel `URL_PKG`

```
URL_PG=${URL_PG:-https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source}
```

A versão atual do PostgreSQL é a 10.3

Então eu criei a seguinte variável:

```
bash-4.4$ echo SVERSION=${SVERSION:-$(lynx --dump ${URL_PG}|awk -F'/' '/v[0-50]/ {print $1}'|cut -c8-12)}
```

Ela me retorna isso abaixo:

```
SVERSION=1.08 1.09 10.0 10.1 10.2 10.3 ttps: ttps: ttps: ttps: ttps: ttps:
```

Como eu crio o comando para pegar o valor maior da pasta dentro do link sendo assim se eu executar ele pegar o nome da pasta "v10.3" e sucessivamente se a versão for 10.4?

para então dar a seguinte saída:

```
bash-4.4$ echo URL_DB=${URL_DB:-${URL_PG}/${SVERSION}}

URL_DB=https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v10.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez o **[sort -V](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html)** possa te ajudar nessa questão.

Exemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash

base_url="https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/"
href_pattern='s/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'

last_version=$(curl -s $base_url | sed -n $href_pattern | grep "v" | sort -V | tail -n 1)
last_url=$base_url$last_version

echo $last_url
```